# How to show that a mapping is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}u^2_2\\2\\u_1-u_2\end{pmatrix}$
>
> Show T is linear.

How can I do this using the rules I know

$i)  \, T(u +v) = T(u) + T(v)$

$ii) \,  T(ru) = rT(u)$ ?

For example, in this case what is $u$ and $v$ for me?

**UPDATE**

> Let $S: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T(\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{pmatrix}) = \begin{pmatrix}u_2^2\\2\\u_1-u_2\end{pmatrix}$. Show $S$ is **not** linear

So I think I've got a solution but want to double check that this answer will suffice. (By the way I let $T = S$

I know that I can use the property

$T(ru) = rT(u)$ and let $u = 0$ to get $T(0) = \begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix} \ne 0 \implies$ **not** linear. Isn't that all I really need to prove that $S$ is not linear

Comment: Will $T(-u)$ ever equal $-T(u)$?

Comment: Depends. What is $u$ what is $v$?

Comment: Also I am not told of that rule yet @Bye_World . I am supposed to prove it based on the following two properties

Comment: It doesn't depend actually.  Try any $u$.  You'll never find that $T(-u)=-T(u)$.  Why?

Comment: But where in the world are you getting that rule from? We aren't even using that yet lol

Comment: I have to use the two properties in my OP

Comment: This is the second property -- I just chose $r=-1$.

Comment: I dont understand how to plug in with what they have given me

Comment: It cannot be linear. $T(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @XianjinYang irrelevant, have to use the two properties

Comment: Just plug in $-\pmatrix{u_1 \\ u_2}$ and see what it maps to.

Comment: But my dilemma is what is $v$ ??

Comment: I'm trying to do the first test $T(u +v)$

Comment: In this case the u and v in the rules is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH @randomgirl

Comment: @randomgirl so $u = u_1$, $v = u_2$ right?

Comment: OK.  This transformation doesn't have that property either.  So just see where $\pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2}+\pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2}$ maps.

Comment: In this case, $u, v$ are vectors. But $T$ is not linear. So, you cannot prove it.

Comment: no @Yusha . Bye-World is giving you examples of elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ like $ \pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2} \text{ and } \pmatrix{b_1 \\ b_2}$

Comment: @Yusha Look that Xinajin Yang **is** using the two rules you said. Perhaps you did not notice, though.

Comment: Editing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers (not to mention the enormous amount of comments) is considerably rude.

Comment: Wasn't doing it to be rude @G.Sassatelli big guy, was a typo.

Comment: I'm not big, and nowhere I said I am a guy. You also [asked the question again](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852654/showing-that-s-is-not-linear).

Comment: Chiming in with G.Sassatelli, because it's the rule. Doesn't sound like a typo, if you reask it the same way.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the question I re-asked for you guys. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

$u,v$ are just elements of a vector space, in your case it is $\mathbb R^2$, that means
$$
u=(u_1,u_2),v=(v_1,v_2) \text{ with } u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\in \mathbb R
$$
$r$ on the other hand is called a *scalar* and in your case the corresponding filed (over which your vector space is defined) is again $\mathbb R$, so $r\in \mathbb R$.

The following was an answer to the question **before editing**:

Now just check for example what @Bye_World already mentioned in the comments to see that 
$$
T(ru) = rT(u)
$$
fails (or check whether the $0$ is mapped to $0$) or just check your first property with 
$$
u=(1,0),v=(0,1)
$$
which gives
$$
T(u+v)=T((1,1))=(1,2,0)\neq(0,2,1)+(1,2,-1)=(1,4,0)=T(u)+T(v)
$$
So $T$ is not a linear mapping.

The following is an answer to the question **after editing**

Here $T$ is indeed linear, the second property is obvious and for the first one we just check
\begin{align}
T(u+v)=T((u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2))&=(u_2+v_2,0,u_1+v_1-u_2-v_2)\\&=(u_2,0,u_1-u_2)+(v_2,0,v_1-v_2)=T(u)+T(v)
\end{align}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42196/discussion-on-answer-by-user190080-how-to-show-that-such-is-linear). It seemed to me that you were done with the exchange.

Answer (score 1):

First, the "rules" you present are not rules, they are the definition of what is meant by "linear."  So they are the correct starting point.

Now you have to decide what addition and scalar multiplication mean when talking about members of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}^3$ to check whether the two definiing properties will hold.  This, I think, is where your confusion comes in.  The problem obviously means to use the usual definitions of addition and scalar multiplication:
$$
\pmatrix{a\\b}+\pmatrix{c\\d}=\pmatrix{a+c\\b+d}\\
\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}+\pmatrix{d\\e\\f}=\pmatrix{a+d\\b+e\\c+f}\\
r\pmatrix{a\\b}=\pmatrix{ra\\rb}\\
r\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}=\pmatrix{ra\\rb\\rc}
$$
With that in mind, if $T$ is liniear then (taking $r = -1$ in the second property)
$$
\forall u_1,u_2: (-1)T\pmatrix{u1\\u2}=T\pmatrix{-u1\\-u2}
$$
But the left side is
$$
\pmatrix{-u_2^2\\-2\\u_2-u_1}
$$
and the right side is 
$$
\pmatrix{u_2^2\\2\\u_2-u_1}
$$
These are never equal, so $T$ is **not** linear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this the way Xianjin Yang showed in the comments. We know $T(ru)=rT(u)$ for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $r=0$ and we have $T(0)=0$ as a special case. But in this example,

$$T(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\0\end{pmatrix} \neq 0$$

Therefore, $T$ is not linear.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, your $u$ and $v$ will be vector in the form $\begin{pmatrix} a\\b\end{pmatrix}$.

To check the first property, let $u = \begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix},v=\begin{pmatrix} c\\d \end{pmatrix}.$ Then we have

$$T(u+v)=T(\begin{pmatrix} a\\b \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} c\\d \end{pmatrix})=T(\begin{pmatrix} a+c \\b+d \end{pmatrix})  \text{......(why?)}$$

You then compute $T(u) + T(v)$. If these two are equal then you are done for the first property. However, I am not saying that $T$ is a linear transformation since I haven't done the computation. But in fact you can tell that $T$ is not a linear transformation. This is a consequence of the following fact:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linear_Transformation_Maps_Zero_Vector_to_Zero_Vector